Install a device owner app on an Amazon fire tablet
I am modernizing an Android App to be used on newer Android Versions. The app is in a standalone environment where the device is single purpose only.
Previously the App ran on Android 10 but the new target will be Android 11.
One of the features requires the app to be run in kiosk mode.
While I have successfully integrated the getActivity().startLockTask() functionality, I have trouble with the Device Owner Setup.
The Tablet I have is an Amazon Fire HD 10 (13. Gen).
This might uniquely disadvantage me.
As soon as I start a freshly wiped tablet, a profile owner is set by default, which prohibits the setup of a device owner app.
After skipping account creation, enabling usb debugging and installing the app,
running
adb shell dpm set-device-owner <activityId>/.MyDeviceAdminReceiver 

yields:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set the device owner, but the user already has a profile owner.

The device does not have NFC nor do I have the afw#setup option either.
Has anyone had success setting a device owner app on an Amazon Fire Tablet and what steps would I need to follow?
